# Laravel valet showing my old image instead of a new image with the same name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, valet

My Laravel valet showing my old image instead of a new image with the same name. I tried to delete the image, but i can still accessing it in valet server. But when i tried to running my app in laravel localhost (using php artisan serve), the image can't be accessed because the image already deleted in public folder.

I also tried to restart the valet server by using valet restart command, but the image where i deleted still exist in valet server.

Comment: Please try hard refresh browser

Comment: valet uses cache. So try hard refresh in browser.

Comment: thanks guys, i already clear the image cache in the browser and thats working